# Как работают слоты в примере календаря vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

На странице:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/calendars#weekly
есть пример с календарем типа week.

Если перейти на https://codepen.io можно увидеть в коде

```html
<!-- the events at the bottom (timed) -->
            <template v-slot:day-body="{ date, timeToY, minutesToPixels }">
              <template v-for="event in eventsMap[date]">
                <!-- timed events -->
                <div
                  v-if="event.time"
                  :key="event.title"
                  :style="{ top: timeToY(event.time) + 'px', height: minutesToPixels(event.duration) + 'px' }"
                  class="my-event with-time"
                  @click="open(event)"
                  v-html="event.title"
                ></div>
              </template>
            </template>
```

Слоты day-body и day-header. Но если их удалить ничего не меняется. Если я правильно понял то эти слоты не используются пока указан events у календаря, но если я его уберу начинают сыпаться ошибки. Есть у кого-нибудь рабочий пример или что-нибудь что натолкнет на решение проблемы? Я хочу выводить свою разметку дня.

Answer (score 0):

Я похоже нашел то что нужно. Странно, но slot:interval - выводит в ячейки, туда куда выводятся события. Я думал interval - это полоска времени слева от календаря. Пока имею результат как на скрине. Дальше думаю дело техники.